24.04: network-manager-openvpn-gnome lost advanced settings
after installing 24.04, there does not seem to be any way to get 'Advanced' settings on network-manager-openvpn-gnome to set parameters such as cypher type, mtu, etc.
Is that a bug or has the setting moved elsewhere?
Thanks, Ondrej

Thanks, I didnt realize that the window got bigger and had to scroll down.Oops..


Open the Settings App and go to network;
Click on the + sign next to VPN. Click on OpenVPN in the next window:

Click on the identity tab on top and go to the Advanced... button at the bottom. You may have to scroll down or increase the size of the window.

MTU is in the General tab:

Cypher options are in the Security tab:


Hope this helps
